# How to access variables in Helper in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, helper

How can I access the variables which are set to the view in CakePHP 3 in a Helper? I did not find anything in the documentation.

In CakePHP 2.x this used to work:

`$this->_View->viewVars['foo'];`

Comment: the same works in cake3, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Reading the API helps.](http://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.View.View.html#_get)

```
 655:     /**
 656:      * Returns the contents of the given View variable.
 657:      *
 658:      * @param string $var The view var you want the contents of.
 659:      * @param mixed $default The default/fallback content of $var.
 660:      * @return mixed The content of the named var if its set, otherwise $default.
 661:      */
 662:     public function get($var, $default = null)
 663:     {
 664:         if (!isset($this->viewVars[$var])) {
 665:             return $default;
 666:         }
 667: 
 668:         return $this->viewVars[$var];
 669:     }
```